# Weird member of float4 structure in the HLSL

Tags: hlsl

I have encountered a weird `x.wwww` component of the `float4 x` vector in a HLSL code. I haven't seen such a member or member function of float4 structures in HLSL, so please tell me what is the meaning of that. It is in the code of this pixel shader:

```
float4 PSConstantColor( PS_PARTICLE_INPUT input ) : SV_TARGET
{
   // Sample particle texture
   float4 vColor = g_baseTexture.Sample( g_samLinear, input.Tex ).wwww;

   // Clip fully transparent pixels
   clip( vColor.a - 1.0/255.0 );

   // Return color
   return vColor;
}
```

At first I thought it should be the `w` component replicated to all the members of the `float4 vColor` vector, but it does not make sense for the color value, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding they are called swizzle operators. In this case they make a float4 of the 4th element in the given float4:

```
vColor = (w, w, w, w)
```

Where w is g_baseTexture.Sample( g_samLinear, input.Tex ).w

Here is an example of a swizzle operator in practice:

```
float3 cross( float3 a, float3 b ) {
    return float3( a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.z*b.y - a.y*b.z );
}
```

and its equivalent swizzle implementation

```
float3 cross( float3 a, float3 b ) {
    return a.yzx*b.zxy - a.zxy*b.yzx;
}
```

Comment: I thought so too, but when I searched MSDN for this `wwww` swizzle operator, as you said, it does not show it as a part of float4 structure. Other operators you mentioned (`xyz`,`zxy` etc.) are clearly explained but non of `wwww` is present.
I searched here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634(v=vs.85).aspx but found nothing about it.

Comment: Yes I got it now, though I still can't understand the meaning of such a color value, except outputing grayscale image of the texture.

Comment: @Pekov - it's not so unusual to use this kind of swizzle, even when you want non-greyscale output. For example, a [CoCg_Y-DXT5](http://www.nvidia.ca/object/real-time-ycocg-dxt-compression.html) decoding shader might use `colour = sample.aaaa` (or equivalently, `sample.wwww`) to "broadcast" the luma component (stored in the alpha channel) to all colour channels as a first step, and then add the Co & Cg chroma offsets to each of r, g, and b in subsequent steps, to tint the initial grey to the desired output colour.

Comment: @Pekov: Those are not actual structure members. They are HLSL language functionality. The compiler generates code for them.